# Pandas: Is there a way to compare two series and find elements that are recent in one series but not the other?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find out if there is a way to know numbers which are there in series B but not in Series A.

```
Series A:
[2,3,4,6,7]

Series B:
[4,5,6,7,8,9]

Output Expected:
[5,8,9]
```

Comment: `A = A.tolist()`
    `B = B.tolist()`
    `print(set(B) - set(A))`

Comment: Do you expect your output sorted in any way or not?

Comment: no the output does not need to be sorted. I only want to know the difference if any between the two series. But more importantly, list of those elements which are present in B but not A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with Boolean indexing:

```
A = pd.Series([2,3,4,6,7])
B = pd.Series([4,5,6,7,8,9])

res = B[~B.isin(A)].values

array([5, 8, 9], dtype=int64)
```

Or a NumPy variant:

```
res = B.values[~np.isin(B.values, A.values)]
```

You can also use `set.difference`:

```
res = list(set(B) - set(A))

[8, 9, 5]
```

Note, however, using built-ins with Pandas / NumPy is usually not optimal.

Comment: Thanks this works. If the series contains large amount of data, what is the suggestion.

Comment: @Learner, I suggest you try all 3 ways and see which works best for you.

Comment: IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

I get the following error if I try with the last method (set difference) Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

Comment: @Learner, That could make sense. The first two should be more memory efficient and potentially more time efficient.

Comment: companyNameSeriesFromCompanies10 = companyNameSeriesFromCompanies.head(1000)
companyNameSeriesFromRounds2 = companyNameSeriesFromRounds2.head(1000)

companyNameSeriesFromRounds2.isin(companyNameSeriesFromCompanies10).values     The result that I get is for only top 10. Do you know why?